# Wordpress Permissions Related Problems

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, wordpress

I've recently set up wordpress, and I've been running through a couple problems that I think are related somehow. First: I couldn't change my permalinks, the classic 404 error that I've been reading tons of articles about without any giving a solution to my case. Second: I can't upload any media data as it says it can't be moved to wp-content/uploads, another classic.
I'm going to post here my apache2.config and my 000-default.config so maybe someone can give me a hand to solve this. You'll notice that I've already set AllowOverwrite to All.
https://pastebin.com/9J2g8L8y - Apache2.conf
https://pastebin.com/Bp5pPZqp - 000-default.conf

Comment: You need to edit the permissions of the folder in order to be able to write to them

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for this. Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: You need to give the `www-data` user write access to the folder.

Comment: I'll check this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the assumption that your WordPress installation is in `/var/www/html`.  Change this and other mentions of it to fit your setup.

***Permalinks 404***

You've set the `AllowOverride All` for `/var/www`, but your DocumentRoot is `/var/www/html`

Edit your `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, and add the following block into the file at about line 175

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

***Unable to Upload***

From your command line, type `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html`

From your command line, type `sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads`

Comment: This solved the problem, but denied me permissions to write on the wordpress folder, do you know how I can make both the www-data and myself the owners of the folder?

Comment: Ok I applied your secondly given command to usr/share/wordpress after creating a local group with two accounts, www-data and myself, and giving this group control over the folder. That settled everything.